# Azure Webjob Fails in Portal But Runs Fine

Tags: azure, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure webjob created using the SDK that runs hourly.  The job runs, and works fine, but when I look at the job in the portal it always shows Failed.  I can run the job from the Debug Console and everything appears fine.  When run from the console the job typically takes seconds to run, but when run on the schedule it usually shows 12-20 minutes, before it fails.

How can I get more details as to why this is failing?  Do I need to be telling webjobs somehow the task is finished and it's waiting on me?

Thanks,
Russ

[Webjob Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2BgL.png)

Comment: Well, duh, Toggle Output shows me more...

[02/06/2020 19:30:07 > bb2ea2: INFO]       Job host started
[02/06/2020 19:48:14 > bb2ea2: ERR ] Command 'cmd /c ""run.cmd""' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
cmd /c ""run.cmd""
[02/06/2020 19:48:14 > bb2ea2: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed

Comment: So it is timing out.  But the job does run.

Comment: When run from the Kudu Console I  see

info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.JobHostService[0]
      Starting JobHost
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Found the following functions:
      CapitalCoverages.WebJobs.Functions.ProcessCoverages
      ...    
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Job host started
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Triggered\Coverages.WebJobs\

Comment: It looks like when it finishes, it starts another job?

Comment: Please provide webJob logs. I suggest you should explicitly return exit code from your app. Also tell if you are using any functions within your job.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens if the job uses `TimerTrigger`.

If the job is long-running use `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` and `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` in Azure app settings instead of `web.config`.

If the job is not long-running, it should have scheduled timers less than 2 minutes, which will probably work well for testing only.

Finally, the ultimate solution is to use `Basic` or `Standard` offering of AppPlan.
In that case you can ENABLE `Always On` to keep the container loaded all the time.
However, `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` and `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` must also be set as described above. Continuous WebJobs or of WebJobs triggered using a CRON (TimerTrigger) expression without `Always On`, will not run reliably.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://developers.de/2018/04/16/azure-webjob-fails-with/).

Comment: This answer is a complete red herring -- I just created a brand new "Worker Service" project (from the .NET Core 3.1 template), deployed it as a triggered web job to a BASIC App Service -- it logs hello world, waits 10 seconds and goodbye world -- all the code runs fine, it looks like it exits fine... -- but Azure insists it's still running even when it's completely done, and eventually it says that the job failed because it timed out. --  There must be a way to tell azure it's done, but it's not clear what that is.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, what I understand is that Azure does not have idea when your process have finished, so it's timer continues accounting even if the process have finished. I don't agree completely with the solution, but I think it gives valid hints to solve the problem.